# Can I somehow see my Docker Hub images being built via Github hooks?

Tags: github, docker, dockerhub

I just authorized [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) Github hook and enabled it in my Github repository, then pushed some changes to the Dockerfile. Is this all I need to do to get my Docker image automatically rebuilt? If so, is there a way I can monitor the build process? I'm using the free versions of both services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I assumed that I should edit the Github repository settings to add a new service binding, but I didn't click "Create Automated Build" in Docker Hub as described here:

> 3. Select “Create Automated Build” from the top right “Create ▼” menu item.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/